# search array function - needs to be more restrictive

Tags: php, arrays, search

I use this function to search arrays:

```
function search_array ( $array, $term )
    {
       foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
            if ( stipos( $value, $term ) !== false )
            $val = str_replace('"',"",preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]=/","",$array[$key]));
               if (isset($val)) return $val;
          return false;
    }
```

This works well, but I need to make is slightly more restrictive.

```
 $a = (search_array($l, "7=")); echo "Device ID: $a";
```

This works, but I only want a match on `7=` and NOT `17=` or `27=` which it's currently doing.
Any idea how I make this ONLY match on what I enter and not try to expand on it ?

Sorry I should have included this function that I'm using in PHP4.

```
function stipos($haystack, $needle){

    return strpos($haystack, stristr( $haystack, $needle ));

}
```

The entrys are similar to ;

1="Device", 3="User", 7="ID123456", 27="Node" etc

If I'm searching for 7=, I'd expect the returned result to be ID123456

Currently I get 2Node being returned which is take from 27="Node"

This is an example of how I'm using this :

```
 $line = "1=\"Device\",3=\"User\",7=\"ID123456\",27=\"Node\"";
 $q = explode(",",str_replace('"','',$line));
 $p = (search_array($q, "7=")); echo "ID : ".$p;
```

I'm looking to return 7=, but I get the value of 27= and the initial 2 from it, resulting in

```
ID : 2Node
```

Not

```
ID : ID123456
```

Comment: Either you have the `stipos()` function defined elsewhere, or this doesn't work. Did you mean `stripos()`?

Comment: What do the values you're searching look like? Where can the string to match appear in them?

Comment: it would be helpfull if you post an example how the Array Looks like.

Comment: example added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using :

```
$line = "1=\"Device\",3=\"User\",7=\"ID123456\",27=\"Node\"";

$value_7 = null;
if(preg_match('#\b7="([^"]*)"#', $line, $matches)) {
    $value_7 = $matches[1];
}
var_dump($value_7);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$strings = array();
$strings[] = '0=';
$strings[] = '1=';
$strings[] = '2=';
$strings[] = '3=';
$strings[] = '10=';
$strings[] = '12=';
$strings[] = 'a2=';
$strings[] = 'a1232=';
$strings[] = ' 4= ';
$strings[] = ' 5= ';
$strings[] = ' 6=a';

foreach($strings as $string)
{
    if(preg_match('/^\d{1}=$/', $string))
    {
        echo $string."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0=
1=
2=
3=
```